# Better way of storing translations in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

What is the best way of storing multilanguage fields in database and updating/accessing to it?
I am handling 6 languages.

Examples with 2 rows and 2 languages

**Option 1:**
Database - 1 table design:

```
table1.products
id --- parent -- product_name
1  ---    5   -- a:2:{s:2:"en";s:3:"dog";s:2:"cs";s:3:"pes"}
2  ---    5   -- a:2:{s:2:"en";s:3:"cat";s:2:"cs";s:5:"macka"}
```

Updating this option 1 is too easy
 1. Merge old translations array with updated or new language fields (PHP array_merge) 
2. Serialize merged array 
3. Simple update database. 

Advantages:

- Less MySQL JOIN procedures
- One table, one row
- Easy handling multiple rows, f.e.: updating X products with Y languages

**Option 2:**
Database - 2 table design:

```
table1.products
id --- parent
1  ---    5  
2  ---    5  

table2.products_translations
product_id --- lang -- product_name
    1      ---  en  -- dog
    1      ---  cs  -- pes
    2      ---  en  -- cat
    2      ---  cs  -- macka
```

Updating this option 2 is a bit harder.

Advantages:

- Better access to one language
- Better database view

What do you mean to be the best database solution? Each product will contain ifinite blocks of texts (descriptions) in all languages.
Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that Postgres can handle JSON data natively giving it a distinct advantage over MySQL in this regard.

Comment: Storing json, arrays, xml, etc in a database is usually discouraged.  You're relying on php, or another language, for analysis that way rather than just SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to store data should be defined by the access patterns on the data, as well as the requirements for data integrity.

Your second solution is the more typical way of storing data in a database.  It is normalized.  It allows you to access any particular language for any product.  More importantly, you can add more languages and easily make changes.  This would be the more desired method.

I wouldn't worry about the performance of the joins.  With proper indexing, this should be quite efficient.

There are some circumstances where the first method might be desirable.  If your underlying code is always using all the languages at the same time, for instance, then returning the structure as a JSON'ish array of arrays of strings may be desirable, with the additional parsing going on in the application layer.  However, returning all products in one particular language would have a lot of performance overhead, particularly if you wanted all products that started with 'A'.  It is also hard to update one particular language value for one product.

My strong inclination would be the second method, unless you have a really, really good reason for the first method.

Comment: Thanks for good description. My back-end (admin site) use always all languages for view to administrators and translators = better 1st method. My front (Web-site) use always only one language = better 2ndmethod. Based on your good suggestion of selecting parts of strings (like 'A') should 1st method bad impact on performance of application. .... So, if we want use SQL search method (%LIKE%) we CAN'T use 1st method. Thanks. @tadman

Comment: One small question: Do you think of using group_concat of languages and subsequently exploding string to array is GOOD solution? Ty.

Comment: @drozdo . . . You can use `group_concat()`.  For performance, it might be faster to fetch the languages on separate rows and do what you want with them in the interface.